# How to understand output of "llvm-profdata show"

Tags: c, linux, llvm, profiler, llvm-clang

I got some profiling data (`code.profdata`) for my process using clang-3.8 build/link [option](http://releases.llvm.org/3.8.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#id39):

```
 -fprofile-instr-generate
```

I generated the output using:

```
llvm-profdata show -all-functions -counts -ic-targets -output=llvm_prof.log  code.profdata
```

1. I am trying to make sense of the but I am not sure how to interpret it, what each field in output means.
2. Is there any llvm tool that can process this data like kcachegrind.

Thanks!

**Data:**

```
Counters:
  fn1:
    Hash: 0x878e8bfe5d1b6a20
    Counters: 8
    Function count: 4464
    Indirect Call Site Count: 0
    Block counts: [4464, 0, 294838272, 0, 4464, 0, 4464]
    Indirect Target Results:
  file1.c:fn2:
    Hash: 0x36804e8dae059d63
    Counters: 6
    Function count: 24576
    Indirect Call Site Count: 0
    Block counts: [24576, 24576, 0, 24576, 24576]
    Indirect Target Results:
  file2.c:fn3:
    Hash: 0x000000000000028a
    Counters: 3
    Function count: 0
    Indirect Call Site Count: 0
    Block counts: [0, 0]
    Indirect Target Results:
  file3.c:fn4:
    Hash: 0x0000000000000000
    Counters: 1
    Function count: 0
    Indirect Call Site Count: 0
    Block counts: []
    Indirect Target Results:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing one step.
LLVM toolchain provides another tool - `llvm-cov`
Output of `llvm-profdata merge` needs to be passed to `llvm-cov` to link the function counter data to source code, like so:

```
llvm-cov show test.bin -instr-profile=merge.out
```

It will generate output:

```
       |    1|#include <stdio.h>
       |    2|#include <stdlib.h>
  1.11k|    3|#define CTR 10
       |    4|
       |    5|int
       |    6|main()
      1|    7|{
      1|    8|    int i, j, k;
     11|    9|    for(i=0; i < CTR; ++i) {
     10|   10|        printf("3: %d", i);
     10|   11|    }
    101|   12|    for(i=0; i < CTR*10; ++i) {
    100|   13|        printf("3: %d", i);
    100|   14|    }
  1.00k|   15|    for(i=0; i < CTR*100; ++i) {
  1.00k|   16|        printf("3: %d", i);
  1.00k|   17|    }
      1|   18|    //  exit(0);
      1|   19|    return 0;

      1|   20|}
```

For completenes, entire flow:

> #1 generate instrumented binary
>
> ```
> clang-9  -g profile_coverage.c  -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping -o profile_coverage
> ```
>
> #2 run binary and get prof data.
>
> ```
> export LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=./llvm_%p.prof 
> ./profile_coverage > /dev/null
> // when program exits, it produces output file llvm_9150.prof
> ```
>
> #3 merge
>
> ```
> $  llvm-profdata-9 merge -output=merge.out -instr llvm_9150.prof
> // outputs merge.out
> ```
>
> #4 coverage with instrumented source
>
> ```
> $  llvm-cov-9 show profile_coverage  -instr-profile=merge.out
> ```

Wrote a blog post covering the whole flow: [link](https://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2018/04/profiling-c-code-with-clang-using.html)